# Karate : I am checking data type of json key which is in float

Tags: karate

Here's the sample json

```
    [
      {
        "studio_name": "TV18_FAMOUS_P1",
        "hostname": "TV18_FAMOUS_P1_TO_AHM_MOTERA_P1_IPL_IP",
        "jitter": "0.12",
        "latency": "11.41",
        "lost_percent": "0.00",
        "time": "2023-04-14 15:55",
        "stadium_name": "AHM_MOTERA_P1_IPL_IP"
      }
    ]
```

When I am trying to assert using this match statement

And match each response.result.twamp contains { latency: '#number' }

my case is getting failed with reason -> path: $[0].latency, actual: '11.15', expected: '#number', reason: not a number

Please suggest

Comment: sorry it is NOT a number, can you work with someone who knows JSON or read this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp